# Can I include a Ghost blog as an iframe or similar within my website?

Tags: seo, blog, iframe, ghost-blog

I'm a web developer with an interest in creating slick data visualisation applications etc.

Most tech websites I see, have some kind of blog. I figure I should have a blog at least - to help with my sites SEO. (Especially as some of the stuff I do will be wordless, it might help to write about it).

I'd like to use Ghost Pro as my CMS - I have no interest in reinventing the wheel, or self hosting Ghost.

Is it possible to use Ghost Pro as CMS for serving pages within a particular URI?

(ie. I'd maintain the same header and footer of my webpage, but serve up the page body from Ghost).

Comment: You could probably do something with an iframe but it's arguably unlikely to help anything with SEO. Search engines do their best to correlate iframes and pages but, so far as I am aware, SEO related perks are more likely to go to your blog site than the site your embedding it in.

Comment: You can host a blog on a subdomain: `blog.example.com` and point that subdomain to some completely separate hosting.   Your blog doesn't have to be tied to your main technology.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - Yes - that's a possibility - but the problem with that is then keeping my two sites theme in sync, etc.